# Does the Stripe front-end Checkout library support subscription selection?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm setting up a payment form on my website using Stripe. They offer a very simple approach to setting up the payment form with minimal work using the `Checkout` development option, which gives you a button and pop-up dialog for credit card info etc.

My use-case is a bit more complicated, because I need to offer customers the option of choosing from a number of subscription plans (which Stripe will know about), and also the provide the ability to update their credit card info (if they are an existing customer with stored card details).

Stripe's `Elements` development option seems to be more suitable, because I can create my own custom form but still embed the necessary inputs using Stripes pre-built controls.

The question I'm asking is whether or not I actually need to go to the trouble of creating a custom form in this way. The Stripe docs are very good, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something given that I would have thought this is a common use-case. In order words, does Stripe provide a pre-built form that allows me to do what I'm trying to do i.e. automatically detect the available subscription plans and populate a dropdown or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options would work in this case. Checkout is a pre-build form that lets you collect card details securely and quickly. It works well on desktop and mobile without much client-side code required. Elements is more flexible and lets you control the form more closely.

Both methods are only the first step though. They really only focus on collecting card details securely and giving you back a card token (`tok_XXXX`) that you then send to your server.

Server-side, you use the token to charge the card once or save it on a customer to charge it multiple times.

You can definitely have a page with multiple plans and prices and still use Checkout. You would either have multiple buttons, one per plan, or you can use [Custom Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom). This lets you attach a click handler to one or multiple buttons on your page which would trigger Checkout to be open. You can then configure the UI to display a custom amount in `handler.open()`.

You can see a basic example in jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y96L9o0d/

You can also remove the `data-amount` or `amount` parameter if you don't want to show a price. Here's an example for using Checkout to update card details: http://jsfiddle.net/6a5vubwj/

Ultimately, none of this creates a subscription or a customer. It's really just step one and the rest happens on your server. So alongside the token, you'd submit information about the plan or product chosen by the customer to create the right subscriptions server-side.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I've been playing with Elements for a while and it seems like if I want the form/dialog to handle subscription plans I really need to a custom form that I'll create myself. It seems relatively painless though. +1 to Stripe for good docs, it makes a big difference!